# Prove that this function is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, periodic-functions

Given the continuous periodic function
$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ 
with a periodic factor of $2$, so that
$$f(x+2)=f(x)$$
and
$$f(0) > f(1)$$
Show that the function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is defines as $g(x) = f(x^2)$, is not uniformly continuous.

I tried writing down the definition of the uniform continuity and starting from there, I also tried assuming that $g$ is uniformly continuous to get a contradiction but I got stuck every time.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For every $\delta>0$ there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that
$$\vert \sqrt{2k} - \sqrt{2k+1}\vert 
= \vert \frac{(\sqrt{2k} - \sqrt{2k+1})(\sqrt{2k} + \sqrt{2k+1})}{(\sqrt{2k} + \sqrt{2k+1})}\vert
=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}<\delta.$$
Furthermore,
$$ g(\sqrt{2k+1})-g(\sqrt{2k})=f(1)-f(0).$$

The definition of uniform continuity would be
$$ \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}: \vert x -y\vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert g(x) - g(y) \vert < \varepsilon. $$
Now we logically negate this statement to get NOT uniformly continuous:
$$ \exists \varepsilon >0 \forall \delta>0 \exists x,y\in \mathbb{R} : \vert x-y\vert < \delta \wedge \vert g(x) - g(y) \vert \geq \varepsilon.$$
Now, for $\varepsilon = f(0) - f(1)$ and a given $\delta>0$ what would you need to pick such that we can show that $g$ is not uniformly continuous? Indeed, exactly $x=\sqrt{2k}$ and $y=\sqrt{2k+1}$ would work for sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: Would you please explain more.Where did you get the $\sqrt{2k+1}$ and the $\sqrt{2k}$

Comment: You want some values which give you back $f(1)$, respectively $f(0)$ when you plug them into $g$. You have to take those, because those are the only values, where you know something about $f$ (namely $f(0)>f(1)$).

Comment: I see. But how did you get to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}\cdot\sqrt{2k+1}}$ in the top part ?

Comment: Sorry, I am tired. Corrected it. It is just the third binomial formula.

Comment: Oh ok. so you have proven that we can find any $|x-y| < \delta$ but how would this help me disprove the uniform continuity ?

Comment: This argument shows that for epsilon=f(0)-f(1), there is no delta that witnesses the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Ok. So that makes a lot more sense now :3. But does it matter that in the top part we took $|x-y|$ and in the bottom part we took $|g(y)-g(x)|$?